# visual foxpro join one column of the table to another table

Tags: foxpro

I have two visual foxpro tables like this:

```
table 1:
Client name    age
Jason          65
Tom            44
Phil           30

table 2: (exactly same client name)
Client name    salary
Jason          100
Tom            200
Phil           300
```

I want to join the two tables like this:

```
Client name    age  salary
Jason          65   100
Tom            44   200
Phil           30   300
```

Can anyone tell me the syntax for that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT table1.customer, table1.age, table2.salary FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.customer = table2.customer